# SVN delete headache what am I doing wrong?

Tags: svn

I am totally confused assuming I am in a working copy and do the following:

```
svn mkdir trunk 
svn mkdir tags 
svn mkdir branches 
svn commit -m "added trunk branches and trunk" 
cd trunk 
touch a b c d e f g 
svn add a b c d e f g 
cd .. 
svn commit -m "added files"
svn copy trunk tags/1.0 
svn commit -m "tagged 1.0"
```

Now I want to delete a file and tag another version

```
 svn delete trunk/e
 svn commit -m "deleted file e"
 svn copy trunk tags/1.1
 svn commit -m "created tag 1.1"
```

I get an error message similar to the following:

> /svn/repos/banana/!svn/wrk/1f39512a-0e1e-11e0-9d1f-5be991158436/63885/tags/1.1/e'
>   path not found

What the heck am I doing wrong here?

**Update:**

I found that if I do an svn update after the delete everything works fine.  I would like an explanation for this behavior.

Comment: One thing to mention is that once you've created your trunk, tags, branches, it's not common practice to maintain a working copy of the entire repository, only usually of a single branch or the trunk in a given working copy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This apparently is a known issue with Subversion, when working with deletes after commits. When you commit, your working copy becomes a **mixed revision** working copy, which then does not allow commits of deletes.

You can verify this by running `svnversion` before you do the updates/commits. You will notice the mixed revision is marked by a working copy version of something like "0:4".

From the Subversion [best practices document](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/doc/user/svn-best-practices.html):

> Your working copy's directories and files can be at different "working" revisions: this is a deliberate feature which allows you to mix and match older versions of things with newer ones. But there are few facts you must be aware of:
>
> 1. After every svn commit, your working copy has mixed revisions. The things you just committed are now at the HEAD revision, and everything else is at an older revision.
> 2. Certain commits are disallowed:
>
>    - You cannot commit the deletion of a file or directory which doesn't have a working revision of HEAD.
>    - You cannot commit a property change to a directory which doesn't have a working revision of HEAD.
> 3. svn update will bring your entire working copy to one working revision, and is the typical solution to the problems mentioned in point #2.
>
> *Book reference*: [The limitation of mixed revisions](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.basic.in-action.html#svn.basic.in-action.mixedrevs.limits).

This is also explained nicely in this article about [mixed revision working copies](http://markphip.blogspot.com/2006/12/mixed-revision-working-copies.html).

Comment: Please update your SVN Book references to use the latest version (nightly) rather than a version that is over 6 years old!  Thanks!

Comment: sorry I did not get a chance to award you the full 50 points I was out sick for a few days thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

The error message also included this

```
svn: Commit failed (details follow): 
svn: File '1.1/e' is out of date
```

I found that if I do an svn update before the copy to tags it works

```
svn delete trunk/e   
svn commit -m "deleted file e"   
svn update 
svn copy trunk tags/1.1   
svn commit -m "created tag 1.1"
```

And that works fine.  An explanation of this behavior would be appreciated.

Comment: This was a godsend. If this happened, use svn revert tags/yourtag, then follow the above.