# SVN commit fails after deleting directory

Tags: svn, version-control

I want to delete a folder, then tag a new version, but keep getting an error.

In trunk I have removed the folder `js/libs` and all its subfolders with `svn rm trunk/js/libs`.
All files under the folder are marked for delete.

I then copy to a new tag with `svn cp trunk tags/0.3.7`, also in the `tags/0.3.7/js/libs` all files and folders are marked for delete. Then when I try to commit with `svn ci -m "v0.3.7"` I get the following error when the commit reaches the first of the nested files of that folder, in the tag:

```
...
Deleting       tags/0.3.7/js/libs
Deleting       tags/0.3.7/js/libs/opentype.js/dist/opentype.js
svn: E155011: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E155011: File '/Users/johannes/Packages/fontsampler-svn/fontsampler/tags/0.3.7/js/libs/opentype.js/dist/opentype.js' is out of date
svn: E160013: '/!svn/txr/1749751-122uf/fontsampler/tags/0.3.7/js/libs/opentype.js/dist/opentype.js' path not found
```

Why does it complain about a missing file when it is marked for delete? The out of date message made me question if there possibly is a 0.3.7 tag already in the repo, but no.

Why can't I commit this delete to a new tag?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4514707/999162) there seems to be a weird behaviour you can get around by committing once before tagging the version.

For me this was resolved like so:
`svn revert tags/0.3.7` - remove tag from current commit

`svn ci -m "deleted folder"` - commit the deletion

`svn up` - somehow sync is necessary

`svn cp trunk tags/0.3.7` - stage the tag

`svn ci -m "tagging version 0.3.7"` - commit your new tag